# Make a filter: Interaction between script and node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to make a filter functionality for a blog. I'm using a node express/ MongoDB/Mongoose setup, and what I want is when a filter is clicked for the 'active' class to be added, and for that filter to be added to an array (filterArray). I then want to compare the filterArray with my posts from Mongoose, and output the matches to a displayArray which I then loop through and output to the page.

So I have two different sets of javascript data - my Mongoose objects (stored in my MongoDB database) and my arrays and functions in my script file. I'm trying to work out how to make the two work with one another.

**My question is:**

If my data is passed through from app.js, how do I reference the DOM in app.js?

**OR**

If I have to use a script to manipulate the dom, how do I reference my mongoose data there?

This is what I have so far:

In my app.js:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error: " + err);
        } else {
            res.render('index', {posts: posts});
        }
    });
});
```

In a separate script file (which I link to in my ejs view):

```
var filterList = ['first item'];
var month = document.getElementsByClassName("post-list__month");

function toggleFilter(element){

    if (element.classList.contains('active')) {
        console.log('active is there so removing it!');
        element.classList.toggle('active');
        filterList = filterList.filter(function(e) { 
            return e !== element.attributes.name.value;
            console.log('Value was removed');
        });
        console.log(filterList);
    } else {
        console.log('active not there so adding it!');
        element.classList.toggle('active');
        filterList.push(element.attributes.name.value);
        console.log(`${element.attributes.name.value} was added to filter list.`);
        console.log(filterList);
    }

}
```

Then in my view for index.ejs (where I'm not yet attempting to action the filtering...):

```
<section class="middle-section">

                <% if(posts.length > 0){ %>
                    <% for (var i = posts.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {  %>
                        <a class="post-link" href="/posts/<%= posts[i]._id %>">
                            <div class="post-body">
                                <div class="post">
                                    <div class="post__heading">
                                        <h2 class="heading-secondary"><%= posts[i].title %></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="post__content">
                                        <p><%= posts[i].body.slice(0, 300) %>...</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tags">
                                        <span class="heading-secondary-date">
                                            Tags: <%= posts[i].categories[0] %>, <%= posts[i].categories[1] %>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="date">
                                        <span class="heading-secondary-date">
                                            <%= posts[i].date %>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <% } %>
                        <% } else { %>
                            <h1>BLOG LIST IS EMPTY<h1>
                                <% } %> 
                            </section>
```

Finally, here's my Mongoose Post schema - I'm going to be comparing the categories to the categories in the filterList:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    date: String,
    categories: [],
    month: String,
    author: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ]
});
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, then you want to manipulate data using a filter. Try passing a query param in your API.

```
app.get('/:filter', function(req, res){
    Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
       if (err) {
          console.log("There was an error: " + err);
       } else {
          var filter = req.params.filter;
          // MAKE DB CALL using the
          res.render('index', {posts: posts});
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: If I did this, would I need to make each filter button pass in a post request?

Comment: Yes. If you are loading lets assume around 50 posts in the first instance itself, then filter it out on the front-end and make a async request for loading more data of that particular filter. Am I making sense to you?

Comment: Yes I think so... but would that mean I would need to refresh the page with each filter?

Comment: No. You'll need to use ajax for this and update your already rendered page.

Comment: OK but wouldn't this also mean that I can only add one filter at a time? I'd like to be able to add multiple filters...

Comment: If you want to pass multiple filters, then try using query strings.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169075/discussion-between-abhishek-gupta-and-raph117).